# mysql - copy from one database to another

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to copy data from one DB into another on the same server. For this I'm using a bash script:

```
mysql -uroot -pMYPW -D "ucb-pvapp" -e "insert into app_daily_quartiles (postcode, lo_limit, hi_limit, median) select (PLZ, loLimit, hiLimit, median) from solarlogmesswerte.tagesquartilekleinraum2"
```

I tried using the dbDest.table notation for the destination too but that gave me an error.

Now I get. `ERROR 1241 (21000) at line 1: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

But I'm not able to find the error.

Using version:  8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Comment: realated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861715/mysql-error-1241-21000-operand-should-contain-1-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove brackets from `select`.
So it should go like

```sql
insert into app_daily_quartiles (postcode, lo_limit, hi_limit, median) 
select PLZ, loLimit, hiLimit, median from solarlogmesswerte.tagesquartilekleinraum2
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Could you explain why?

Comment: Probably mysql tries to treat that as subquery (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-errors.html) or as a row constructors (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/row-subqueries.html).